# Pass variable path in dir() jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have created a jenkinsfile in which I need to go into an already created directory. But the problem is that the name of the directory can be variable, eg: `dir ('RELEASE/abc/${abc-version}')`. The `abc-version` is passed as a string argument in the pipeline.

The problem is that, on running the pipeline, jenkins creates a directory named as "`${abc-version}`" rather than passing it as an argument.

I have failed in doing so till now. Is this even possible? Can we pass a variable in the dir step?

**EDIT:** I tried with %abc-version% and it still doesn't work. It instead creates a directory with %abc-version% rather than taking it as a variable.

Also, my parameter is like: `abc-version`. Has it anyting to do with the problem?

Comment: try `dir ('RELEASE/abc/%abc_version%')`

Comment: @TalhaJunaid it creates a new folder with `%abc-version%`

Comment: Use double quotes (`"RELEASE/abc/${abc-version}"`)

Comment: I am seeing something similar... I am calling an external method in a groovy file that I load (i.e. `script.utils = load "common.groovy"`) and then when I get the dynamic directory (i.e. `final String dynamicDir = script.utils.whateverMethod()`) it seems that the dir command always creates / replaces the directory instead of using the existing one. I have tried `dir(dynamicDir)` and `dir("${dynamicDir}")` but neither works. Of course, specifying a string literal, i.e. `dir("dynamicDirValue")` works... any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use double quotes

```
dir ("RELEASE/abc/${abc_version}")
```

in groovy Single quotes are a standard Java String while Double quotes are a templatable String

e.g

```
a = 10
b = "RELEASE/abc/${a}"
c = 'RELEASE/abc/${a}'
print(b)
print('\n')
print(c)
```

output will be

```
RELEASE/abc/10
RELEASE/abc/${a}
```

You can try it [here](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5129354283581440)

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But had to change `${abc-version}` to `${abc_version}`. Else it was giving a binding error!

Answer (score 3):

We need to use double quotes to resolve variable in groovy script.

use the following sample code

```
def dirpath = "RELEASE/abc/${abc-version}"
dir(dirpath){
  //logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def proc1 = generateScriptCmd.execute(null, new File(sRootDir));
```

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the Low Quality Queue. Code only answers are not considered good answers, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are less useful to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / better than existing answers.